# Change render device from Sandy Bridge GPU to main GPU

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

I'm trying to force my application to use the main gpu. Now it automatically takes the one on the CPU. I have tried it both with DirectX9 and OpenGL.

DirectX returns only 1 adapter when I call the GetAdapterCount() function.
OpenGL also returns only 1 adapter when I call glGetString( GL_RENDERER ).

Is there a way to make sure it uses the right GPU?

Comment: Which is the "right" GPU? The easiest way is to configure your operating system to use the video card adapter you want. You can also disable on-board video adapter from CMOS if it keeps switching back to it.

Comment: This is not only for the pc I'm developing it on. I want to be sure it runs on the faster of the two GPU's on every PC the program will ever run on.

Comment: "faster"?  By what metric(s)?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my Nvidia Optimus + SandyBridge CPU laptop. EVerybody (DX, GL) returned only one adapter, that gave me Intel GPU.

I fixed this by updating Nvidia driver. After installing latest version DirectX correctly reported two adapters and based on vendord id (Intel vs Nvidia) I could choose which GPU to use in my application.

Alternatively you can go to Nvidia Control Panel, and create profile for your executable - and set for it to always use Nvidia GPU. Of course this won't solve same issue if you give your executable to other people to run on their systems with bad drivers.

Another options would be to rename your executable to popular game executable name. Like rage.exe or bf3.exe. This works because Nvidia Control Panel has a lot of predefined profiles with popular game exe names, and all they are set to use Nvidia GPU instead of Intel GPU.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of the Nvidia driver. But still no luck. Now I'm trying to update the Intel® HD Graphics Driver. Hopefully that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated and hardware dependent.  Are you on a laptop with hybrid graphics?  If so, generally the drivers are set up to give you the "main" GPU for an OpenGL context (falling back to the integrated graphics for desktop rendering).  If it's a desktop, usually the two GPUs drive physically distinct monitor outputs.  Do you have a monitor plugged into the discrete graphics card.

Comment: I thought that too, but what ever I do it only gives me the integrated gpu.